# How do I make dynamic navigation child menus active when clicked in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am retrieving side bar navigation from database.The navigation contains its child menus.I want to make child menus active when clicked.For this purpose I don't want to use jquery. My code for menus is below.

```
@foreach($parent as $parent)
 {{$parent->name}}
@foreach($child as $child)
 {{$child->name)
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Please any one can help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my question.First we will add anchor tag to child menus in sidebar-blade.php.We can see that we are retrieving URL query string from database.So in this case we will make a condition for our active class and our code would look like this.

```
 <ul>
 @foreach($parent as $parent)
 <li><a href="#">{{$parent->name}}</a>
 <ul>
 @foreach($child as $child)
 @if(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] == $child->name)
 <li class="active"> 
 @endif
 <a href="http:example.com?name=$child->name">{{$child>name)}}</a>
 </li>
 @endforeach
  </ul>
  </li>
@endforeach 
</ul>
```